# Hi, Im trying to use a script that will create a google sheets drawing on a spreadsheet tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like a script that I can assign to a button on my google sheets that will create a drawing which can be manually create by going to Insert > Drawing.

I tried recording a macro but it doesn't record the creation and insertion of the drawing.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to do it in a sidebar and use <input type="button"...

Comment: I don't think you can script Google Drawings